# Is there a way to intentionally slow down IntelliSense?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, ide, intellisense

I have a large C# source file (~5k lines) that I'm trying to wrangle.  I'm not always adding or removing curly braces, but when I do, IntelliSense gets way too excited populating the Error List pane with error notifications.  Though this doesn't cause more than a heartbeat of slowdown I find it irritating as a moment later I've rectified the extra `{` or missing `}` and the number climbs back down.

I know that if I move focus from the Error List pane this would not be an issue, but I prefer to keep it on screen.  Is there a way to retard IntelliSense's update cycle?

Comment: 5k lines in a file. I smell code rot.

Comment: @Cubicle.Jockey 1.  This is nothing, my last job had a file that was exactly (2^15 - 1) lines long, with a 7k line long function, and a 1k line long "if" check where the indenting from nested "if"s brought it over a full screen...with a "goto" in the middle.  This project is rather pleasant and relaxing.

Comment: Here is the documentation for Intellisense Options. You can turn it off while you are in the file or change how it is triggered.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ecfczya1(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: "... 7k line long function, and a 1k line long "if" check where the indenting from nested "if"s brought it over a full ... " how did VS handle that?

Comment: @jHilscher I don't recall VS2003 having any issues with it, IIRC the rough part was navigating through the virtual machine and through (hosted?) by ClearCase; once a day _something_ would crash when I tried to compare items in the version tree.  If I had to guess I'd say it was because .NET 1.1 had relatively few features and the code itself had relatively few relations whose statuses had to be kept up with.

Comment: IIRC, the development team completely rewrote how Intellisense works some time after VS2003, so it's not surprising that it works differently in VS2010.